# Antivirus (avast) finding infected files in another program's (AdwCleaner) quarantine folder

Tags: anti-virus, avast

avast didn't flag all the files in the AdwCleaner quarantine folder, just two of them.

Is this a problem?

I assume that because the files are in the quarantine folder it shouldn't be a concern, but is this a dangerous assumption?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make an exclusion rule for that folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are adequately quarantined, there should be no problem. Why are you keeping quarantined files on your computer?

Comment: A good question with a bad answer: I've been lazy. I'll delete them.